# Compile Error - Expected Array while updating pivot

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors, pivot

I'm trying to automate a pivot table to it uses the lowest value of a column as the filter for the pivot.

The value in Cell H6 is what will be updating the filter for the pivot, but I need this value to be dynamic and change to the lowest value in column W, However, the code doesn't work with a formula in the cell as it's not viewing it as a value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Update by Extendoffice 20180702
    Dim xPTable As PivotTable
    Dim xPFile As PivotField
    Dim xStr As String
    On Error Resume Next
    If Intersect(Target, Range("H6:H7")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xPTable = Worksheets("cumulative sales pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
    Set xPFile = xPTable.PivotFields("Issue Day Of Sale ID")
    xStr = Target.Text
    xPFile.ClearAllFilters
    xPFile.CurrentPage = xStr
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

    Range("H6").Select
    Range("H6").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas("=MIN(W:W)")
    Range("H6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

The first part the code works but the second part is giving me

> "Compile Error - Expected Array"

Any ideas where i'm going wrong?

Comment: `Range("H6").Value = Application.Min(Range("W:W"))`? It looks like that's what you're trying to do in those couple lines.

Comment: [Avoid .select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) where possible.

Comment: Assuming `Range("H6").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas("=MIN(W:W)")` is there error line, your `xlPasteFormulas` refers to pasting a formula from the source cell, which does not include the formula to be pasted; that is not the same as `Range("H6").Formula = "=Min(W:W)"` which appends a formula to a cell.  You would receive a compile error since the syntax as written would not be able to be compiled.  [See PasteSpecial documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial).

Answer (score 0):

Typing out comment as an answer.  Note that BigBen's comment would resolve the issue, so capturing that here, as well:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Range("H6").Value = Application.Min(Range("W:W"))
End Sub
```

---

Now to your compile error:

The compile error occurring at `Range("H6").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas("=MIN(W:W)")` is due to syntax.

Within the [documentation for Range.PasteSpecial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial) you will notice that the arguments are for action of pasting.

As writting, the `("=MIN(W:W)")` tacked onto the `xlPasteFormulas` would flag the error, where the compiler is seeing the `()` as being applicable to an array.  That is why you got the error you received.

---

Now, onto appropriate use of `Range.PasteSpecial`... `Range.PasteSpecial (Paste, Operation, SkipBlanks, Transpose)` has 4 possible arguments.  I will leave the further explanation to the documentation about what can fill each argument, but will give an example of a couple `Paste` arguments which are common:

```
'Pastes the value from the copied cell
Cells(1,1).Copy
Cells(2,2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Pastes the formula from the copied cell
Cells(1,1).Copy
Cells(2,2).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
```

Note that in the above, both require that the formula or value comes from the copied cell.

If you want to append a formula to a cell, you can use `Range.Formula`, such that:

```
Cells(1,1).Formula = "=Min(B:B)"
```

---

Hopefully that both explains the issue and resolves your problem.